# Unify ZF2 Translator and AngularJS localization

Tags: php, json, angularjs, zend-framework2

I built an application that uses ZF2 for authentification, routing, error pages etc., but the core functionalities on each view are implemented in AngularJS. The whole thing is localized, but in 2 seperate instances:

We have the ZF2 Translator, configured in module.config.php

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
        ),
    ),
),
```

containing key=>value pairs like `'app.frontend.title' => 'Title'`.

And the Angular-Translate module, configured by

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/lang/',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

containing a nested JSON object like `{'app': {'buttons': {'send': 'Send now'}}}'`

The PHP part contains some headlines, content for `<title>`, navigation,... pretty much everything that is displayed outside of my AngularJS apps. The Angular-JSON contains l10n for a lot of buttons, dialogs etc.

Is there a possibility to unify these two? Doesn't matter if I access the AngularJS json file from the php script or the other way round (get the .json dynamically served by PHP for Angular). But I can't figure out how to read JSON for the ZF2 Translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would have you have some translations handled by PHP and some others by Angular JS? Couldn't you get rid of the ZF2 Translator?

Comment: This would require to rebuild the whole app and let AngularJS also manage routing, navigation etc.. I cant do this because other components/modules of the application are completely implemented in just php/ZF2.

Comment: I decided to rebuild and develop an SPA based on AngularJS with ZF2 as REST API only.